# Enable/disable cell editing based on a particular column's value for each row

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I have a jquery editable datatable and all columns are editable. I want to enable/disable cell editing based on a particular cell value. For example in below table if Operating System value is "Windows" make column "FileExtension" as non-editable and if Operating System value is "Unix" make column "Language" as non-editable .

```
 --------------------------------------------------
| OperatingSystem  FileExtenstion   Language       |
 --------------------------------------------------
| Windows          non-editable     editable       |
| Unix             editable         non-editable   |
| Windows          non-editable     editable       |
 --------------------------------------------------
```

Table is getting populated dynamically via Ajax source.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dbResultsTable").dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/EditableTables/TableEditAjaxRequest",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bJQueryUI": false,
            "scrollX" : true,
             "aoColumns": [
                          {  "sName": "OperatingSystem",
                          },
                           {
                             "sName": "FileExtenstion",
                            },
                             { 
                              "sName": "Language",
                             }
                  ]
     }).makeEditable({
        "aoColumns": [
                          {
                              cssclass: "required"
                          },
                            {
                              cssclass: "required"
                          },
                          {
                              cssclass: "required"
                          }
                      ]
                      }
                      );
    });
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: It shouldn't be very complicated to do. But you have to post some code. I made that kind of filtering for datable+editable using PHP. BTW - is this Ajax based datable or static?

Comment: @phillip100 : thanks for helping me out . Yes its Ajax based table. Updating question with sample code , can you guide me how do i achieve this

Comment: How do you assign `editable` to fields? I guess you have something like: `$('.editable').editable({ ... });`, so, where do you set the `editable` class for editable fields? while server side rendering?

Comment: @phillip100 : I am new to jquery , so made my table editable using following post http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/193068/Adding-data-management-CRUD-functionalities-to-the .

Comment: @phillip100 : In jquery.dataTables.editable lib function for editing cell i suppose " function _fnApplyEditable(aoNodes) {
        var oDefaultEditableSettings = {         event: 'dblclick',
            "callback": function (sValue, settings) {
                properties.fnEndProcessingMode();
                if (sNewCellValue == sValue) {
                    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
                    oTable.fnUpdate(sNewCellDisplayValue, aPos[0], aPos[2]);
                    properties.fnOnEdited("success");
                } else {....
                }              "

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really familiar with Java. I probably also confused what you meant by ***editable*** I thought you use two independent jquery plugins like I did (I should have been carefully read the tags).

Comment: @phillip100 no problem... But can you give me sample or some idea how you did it in php.. I will try to do the same in java

Comment: I found one way to do this  :-$("#dbResultsTable tr").live("mousedown", function() {
     if ($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text()=="Windows") {
         $(this).find("td:eq(2)").empty().unbind(); 
     }
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found one way to do this , I hope it help someone .

```
$("#dbResultsTable tr").live("mousedown", function() {
        if ($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text()=="Windows") {
            $(this).find("td:eq(1)").empty().unbind(); 
        } else if($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text()=="Unix"){
             $(this).find("td:eq(2)").empty().unbind(); 
            }
    });
```

Note :- but this wont update data on server side if your cell have some data and you have cleared+disabled it using above function. You will have to make an ajax call and update cell data .

Please let me know if any better way to do this ,I am all ears.